# Update mvc partialview with jquery call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a partial view that contains all the post made on a blog. When a new post is made a button appear and informs users that a new one has been made and they can click on the button and it should refresh the partial view.

Here is my code:
**_PartialFontPagePost.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<Live_Blog.Models.Post>
@using Live_Blog.Tools

@foreach (var Post in Model)
{
    <div class="post-preview">
        <a href="/Blog/@Post.Url">
            <h2 class="post-title">
                @Post.Title
            </h2>
            @if (Post.SmallTitle.Length > 0)
            {
                <h3 class="post-subtitle">
                    @Post.SmallTitle
                </h3>
            }
        </a>
        <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">@Post.PostedBy</a> on @Helper.FirstCharToUpper(Post.DateCreated.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"))</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
}
```

**Part of html page and script**

```
<div class="refreshContent">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialFontPagePost", Model)
</div>
<script>
    $('#Refresh').click(function () {
        $('.refreshContent').load('@(Url.Action("Update_PartialFontPagePost", "Blog", null))');
    })
</script>
```

**The function in the BlogController**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Update_PartialFontPagePost()
{
    var post = db.Post.OrderByDescending(i => i.DateCreated);
    return PartialView("_PartialFontPagePost", post.AsEnumerable());
}
```

I know that the Partial view works and show the correct data when you load the page, but when I click the Button it "throws" the entire html side into the `refreshContent` div. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

**Edit**
`@Satpal` After a click on the button, the `refreshContent` looks like this

```
<div class="refreshContent">
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home - Blog</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/clean-blog.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/reset/reset-min.css">
    <link href="/Content/Editor.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    ... Basic it loads all the html of the entire page.
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate _but when I click the Button it "throws" the entire html side into the `refreshContent`_?

Comment: why don't you clear the (.refreshContent) div data when your call succeeded, or use ajax call to get new post.. both are sufficient way..

Comment: @Satpal I made an edit of the post. Hope it makes sense now